# Signup form cleaned_data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

## Hi,

i have a custom signup form and i use django localflavors as field validation for two of the fields. I have built a custom validation and it works fine, but when i return cleaned data the form skips the validations that comes with the local flavor fields.

to sum the problem when i define my own custom clean_data function for validation it overrides the django locolaflavors validation.

## The form

```
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name', required=True)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name', required=True)
sec_id = SEPersonalIdentityNumberField(max_length=30, label='Pid', required=True)
org_nr = SEOrganisationNumberField(max_length=30, label='Org_nr', required=True)
telephone = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='Telephone', required=True)
address = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Address', required=True)
city = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='City', required=True)
zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Zip_code', required=True)
state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTY_CHOICES,label='State', required=True)
country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRY_LIST,label='Country', required=True)
```

## My custom validation

```
def clean(self):
    """
    Clean the form
    """
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    secid= self.cleaned_data["sec_id"]


    if User.objects.filter(profile__sec_id=sec_id).exists():
        self.add_error(
            'sec_id',
            _('If you have a account please reset your password'),
        )
        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned_data creating, after form is using is_valid, so that before use clean, you should use is_valid

Comment: Ive looked at the Django documentation but do not understand where i should use is_valid() and how to instigate in. Do you have a exampel? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by not overidning the default clean() method. Instead i renamed my custom validation and user raise ValidationError, and it al works:

```
  def clean_secid(self):
    sec_id= self.cleaned_data['sec_id']
    if User.objects.filter(profile__sec_id=sec_id).exists():
        raise ValidationError("If you have a account please reset your password")
    return sec_id
```